# SQL - Find differences based on a column in snapshot table

Tags: sql

I have a history table where a scheduled job inserts once per day the result of a view with a timestamp. The table looks like this:

| Day | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210605 | A | 100 |
| 20210605 | B | 80 |
| 20210605 | C | 80 |
| 20210604 | A | 100 |
| 20210604 | B | 80 |
| 20210604 | C | 90 |
| 20210603 | A | 120 |
| 20210603 | B | 80 |
| 20210603 | C | 90 |

How do I write a query that shows the price variations from one day to another?
In this case the result should look like this:

| Name | DayBefore | PriceBefore | DayAfter | PriceAfter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20160603 | 120 | 20160604 | 100 |
| C | 20160604 | 90 | 20160605 | 80 |

Comment: Can you explain why there are only two rows in the expected output, and why only names `A` and `C` appear?

Comment: Because B's price never changed in the three days. Instead on 20160604 C's price was 90 and the day next became 80. Same for A: on 20160603 the price was 120 and the day next was 100. I need to see the price variations of the records between two days next to each other.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I am using postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below query tested in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6f17fa12ff2c61b8b64ba58f4f6b5e6)

```
select Name, 
cast(DATEADD(day, -1, Day)as date) as DayBefore,
prevPrice as PriceBefore,
Day as DayAfter, 
Price as PriceAfter
from
(select name, Day, Price,
LAG(Price, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Day) AS prevPrice
from test) a
where prevPrice <> 0 and prevPrice <> price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
Create table DataTable(Day varchar(100),    Name varchar(10),   Price float)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210605',   'A',    100)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210605',   'B',    80)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210605',   'C',    80)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210604',   'A',    100)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210604',   'B',    80)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210604',   'C',    90)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210603',   'A',    120)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210603',   'B',    80)
Insert into DataTable values( '20210603',   'C',    90)

Select a.name,
b.Day as DayBefore , b.price as PriceBefore,a.day as DayAfter, a.Price as PriceAfter 
from DataTable a
left join DataTable b on a.Day = dateadd(day,1,b.day) and a.name = b.name
where b.day is not null
and a.price <> b.price
Order by a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lag function partitioning by name and ordering by day descending.

```
-- Auxiliary data for testing purposes
with aux (Day,  Name,   Price) as (
    select '20210605',  'A',    100 from dual union all
    select '20210605',  'B',    80 from dual union all
    select '20210605',  'C',    80 from dual union all
    select '20210604',  'A',    100 from dual union all
    select '20210604',  'B',    80 from dual union all
    select '20210604',  'C',    90 from dual union all
    select '20210603',  'A',    120 from dual union all
    select '20210603',  'B',    80 from dual union all
    select '20210603',  'C',    90 from dual)

-- Actual query
SELECT
    name,
    to_date(day, 'YYYYMMDD') day_before,
    price price_before,
    LAG(to_date(day, 'YYYYMMDD')) OVER(
        PARTITION BY name
        ORDER BY
            to_date(day, 'YYYYMMDD') DESC
    ) day_after,
    LAG(price) OVER(
        PARTITION BY name
        ORDER BY
            to_date(day, 'YYYYMMDD') DESC
    ) price_after
FROM
    aux;
```

Output:

```
NAME DAY_BEFORE PRICE_BEFORE DAY_AFTER PRICE_AFTER
--------------------------------------------------
A     05-JUN-21          100
A     04-JUN-21          100 05-JUN-21         100
A     03-JUN-21          120 04-JUN-21         100
B     05-JUN-21           80        
B     04-JUN-21           80 05-JUN-21          80
B     03-JUN-21           80 04-JUN-21          80
C     05-JUN-21           80        
C     04-JUN-21           90 05-JUN-21          80
C     03-JUN-21           90 04-JUN-21          90
```

Try it out here: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e0e9e49736382e550413b935e4a4798)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `lead()`/`lag()` to get data from adjacent days along with some filtering:

```
select name, day as day_before, price as price_before, day_after, price_after
from (select t.*,
             lead(day) over (partition by name order by day) as day_after,
             lead(price) over (partition by name order by day) as price_after
      from t
     ) t
where price_after <> price;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e074c6e9d748517a209c5ee9d5d32dcf) is a db<>fiddle.